# Wrong condition match and output

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess
from subprocess import call
import sys, termios
print "A list of food that we recommend while you are in Rajasthan \n"
print "> Dal Bati Churma"
print "> Laal Maas"
print "> Gatte ki Khichdi"
print "> Rajasthani Kadi"
print "> Gatte ka Pulao"
print "> Churma Ladoo"
print "> Badam ka Halwa"
print "> Gujia"
print "I can show you a few food images"
show=raw_input("What do you want to see? \n")
while 1:
    if show is 'Gujia' or 'gujia': 
        call(['bash','gujia.sh'])
        termios.tcflush(sys.stdin, termios.TCIOFLUSH)
        break
#   subprocess.call(["gujia.sh"])
    elif input is 'Dal Bati Churma' or 'dal bati churma':
        call(['bash','dbc.sh'])
        break
#   subprocess.call(['dbc.sh'])
    elif input is 'Laal Maas' or 'laal maas' or 'lal maas':
        call(['bash','lm.sh'])  
        break   
#   subprocess.call(['lm.sh'])
    elif input is 'Gatte ki Khichdi' or 'gatte ki khichdi':
        call(['bash','gkk.sh'])
        break
#   subprocess.call(['gkk.sh'])
    elif input is 'Rajasthani Kadi' or 'rajasthani kadi':
        call(['bash','rk.sh'])
        break
#   subprocess.call(['rk.sh'])
    elif input is 'Gatte ka Pulao' or 'gatte ka pulao':
        call(['bash','gkp.sh'])
        break
#   subprocess.call(['gkp.sh'])
    elif input is 'Churma Ladoo' or 'churma ladoo':
        call(['bash','cl.sh'])
        break
#   subprocess.call(['cl.sh'])
    elif input is 'Badam ka Halwa' or 'badam ka halwa':
        call(['bash','bkh.sh'])
        break
#   subprocess.call(['bkh.sh'])
    else: 
        print "I am not sure what you want?"
os.system("python food.py")
print "Now don't wait up and get something to eat"
```

I am trying to match a string say "Gujia" and then execute a particular shell script associated with it however no matter what i enter it always runs the very first loop I tried commenting out "Gujia" case but then also it just keep on calling the if/elseif loop at top

Comment: You need to use "==" operator to check for equality: `if show == 'Gujia' or show == 'gujia':`

Answer (score 0):

```
show=raw_input("What do you want to see? \n")
while 1:
    if show in ('Gujia', 'gujia'): 
        call(['bash','gujia.sh'])
        termios.tcflush(sys.stdin, termios.TCIOFLUSH)
        break
```

try this method above it will work,

if show in ('words', '...', '....', '...')
it will search for words if match one of them execute the code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are making several mistakes as below.

1. `show=raw_input("What do you want to see? \n")` needs to be inside the `while 1` loop, I think.
2. For string comparison, you need to use `==`, sadly.
3. `show is 'Gujia' or 'gujia'` is `(show is 'Gujia') or ('gujia')`, actually. And `'guija'` is not empty string, it is always true.
4. There are many `elif input ...`, but maybe 'input' is 'show', isn't it?

So, taken those conditions together:

```
while 1:
    show=raw_input("What do you want to see? \n")
    show = show.lower() # translate strings to lower case.
    if show == 'gujia': 
        call(['bash','gujia.sh'])
        termios.tcflush(sys.stdin, termios.TCIOFLUSH)
#   subprocess.call(["gujia.sh"])
    elif show == 'dal bati churma':
        call(['bash','dbc.sh'])
    ...
```